# Merge datasets in Python or R using datetime variable

Tags: python, r, timestamp, python-datetime

I have two different datasets that need merging.

- First dataset has the data per minute
- Second data has the information per hour.

I would like to aggregate all the data in the first dataset to hours from minutes (01/12/2020 00:00, 01/12/2020 00:01, 01/12/2020 00:02....01/12/2020 00:59) to **01/12/2020 to 00:00**.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to @nehalem's Python solution, here is one using R. The [`lubridate` package](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/) is wonderful and makes working with dates and times easy.

First, convert your series of date-time characters into a date-time object.

```
library(lubridate)
series <- c("01/12/2020 00:00", "01/12/2020 00:01", "01/12/2020 00:02", "01/12/2020 00:59", "01/12/2020 04:20")
series2 <- parse_date_time(series, "d m y H M") # specify current format of your data
```

This will give:

```
> series2
[1] "2020-12-01 00:00:00 UTC" "2020-12-01 00:01:00 UTC" "2020-12-01 00:02:00 UTC"
[4] "2020-12-01 00:59:00 UTC" "2020-12-01 04:20:00 UTC"
```

Finally, round the minutes to hours:

```
> series3 <- floor_date(series2, "hour")
> series3
[1] "2020-12-01 00:00:00 UTC" "2020-12-01 00:00:00 UTC" "2020-12-01 00:00:00 UTC"
[4] "2020-12-01 00:00:00 UTC" "2020-12-01 04:00:00 UTC"
```

Additionally, the documentation contains information about options to change, among other things, the time zone and time format depending on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are coming from R, if you want to use Python for tabular data have a look at `pandas` which offers a comprehensive set of tools for processing such datasets.

There, I think you are looking for [pandas.Series.dt.floor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html?highlight=pandas%20dt%20floor#pandas.Series.dt.floor) which allows you to perform a floor operation to the intended time unit, here hours:

```
series = pd.Series(
    ['2020-01-01 12:01:00', '2020-01-01 12:02:00', '2020-01-01 12:30:00', '2020-01-01 12:59:00'],
    name='timestamp',
    dtype="datetime64[ns]"
)
series.dt.floor('H')
```

This will return

```
0   2020-01-01 12:00:00
1   2020-01-01 12:00:00
2   2020-01-01 12:00:00
3   2020-01-01 12:00:00
```